# How to get the maximum and minimum number in Java?

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am new to Java. I have to write a code to get the maximum and minimum numbers that the user have in putted.

This is the exact question

> Write a program that accepts 100 real numbers from the command prompt
>   and determine the largest and smallest values. You are not allowed to
>   use "if-else" statement.
>
> Hint - Use Math.max(number, largest) and Math.min(number, smallest)
>   methods.

This is the code that I wrote but I don't know why it wont work

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LargestAndSmallest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] inputtedNumber = new int[20];

        for (int num = 0; num < 20; num += 1) {
            inputtedNumber[num] = in.nextInt();
        }

        int maxNum = 0, minNum = 0;

        for (int checkNum = 0; checkNum < 20; checkNum += 1) {
            maxNum = Math.max(inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
            minNum = Math.min(inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
        }

        System.out.println("The maximum number: " + maxNum);
        System.out.println("The minimum number: " + minNum);
    }
}
```

I don't know why but I get this error message

```
maxNum = Math.max(inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
                         ^
    method Math.max(int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.max(long,long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.max(float,float) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.max(double,double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
error: no suitable method found for min(int)
            minNum = Math.min(inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
                         ^
    method Math.min(int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.min(long,long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.min(float,float) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.min(double,double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
2 errors
```

Comment: I know we need to input 100 number but I make it 20 just for testing..

Comment: as promoted in the exception message (and even the hint says so) you need to pass two parameter to `Math.min` and `Math.max`, currently you only pass one.

Comment: I can recommend you to always keep the javadoc when coding, here you can see the documentation for the method [Math.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-)

Comment: Why the hassle with min and max? read the numbers into an array, sort it, print the values at the first and the last index.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider because that's not what the teacher asked, and because that is less efficient.

Comment: code review: you can put the repeated number 20 (or 100) in a variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-), `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` take in two arguments, however you are only ever providing one.

You will need to change this:

```
    int maxNum = 0, minNum = 0;

    for (int checkNum = 0; checkNum < 20; checkNum += 1) {
        maxNum = Math.max(inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
        minNum = Math.min(inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
    }
```

To this:

```
    int maxNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int checkNum = 0; checkNum < 20; checkNum += 1) {
        maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
        minNum = Math.min(minNum, inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
    }
```

Setting `maxNum` to 0 will cause problems if all your numbers are negative, since none of them will be larger than 0. Setting `minNum` to 0 will cause problems if all your numbers are positive, since none of them will be lower than 0.

As an alternative, you could set the both of them to `inputtedNumber[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Math.max requires 2 integers to compare, thats why you are getting the error.
you can do it like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LargestAndSmallest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] inputtedNumber = new int[20];

        for (int num = 0; num < 20; num += 1) {
            inputtedNumber[num] = in.nextInt();
        }

        int maxNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE, minNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int checkNum = 0; checkNum < 20; checkNum += 1) {
            maxNum = Math.max(inputtedNumber[checkNum], maxNum);
            minNum = Math.min(inputtedNumber[checkNum], minNum);
        }

        System.out.println("The maximum number: " + maxNum);
        System.out.println("The minimum number: " + minNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MinMax mm = new MinMax();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Geef getal %d: ", i + 1);
            int getal = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            mm.evalueerGetal(getal);


        }
        System.out.printf("Het grootste getal was %d.\n", mm.getMaximum());
        System.out.printf("Het kleinste getal was %d.\n", mm.getMinimum());
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MinMax {

    // private int getal;
    private int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public void evalueerGetal(int getal) {

        if (getal < minimum)
            minimum = getal;
        if (getal > maximum)
            maximum = getal;

    }

    public int getMaximum() {

        return maximum;
    }

    public int getMinimum() {
        return minimum;
    }

}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`Math.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) take two parameters and compares them. You passed only one parameter to the method. From javadoc:

> **Returns the greater of two int values.**

Here is an example on how to use `Math.max`

```
int first = ...
int second = ...
int max = Math.max(first, second);
```

The same happens for `Math.min`

To compare n numbers simply compare them 2 by 2, as an example

```
int[] inputtedNumber = ...
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int x : inputtedNumber) {
    max = Math.max(x, max);
    min = Math.min(x, min);
}
// Here max has the maximum value of the list
// Here min has the minimum value of the list
```

Comment: I did loop it... how am i suppose to pass 100 numer into it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with that you were not using the Math.max method properly, try the below code to run this properly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] inputtedNumber = new int[20];

    for (int num = 0; num < 20; num += 1) {
        inputtedNumber[num] = in.nextInt();
    }

    int maxNum = inputtedNumber[0], minNum = inputtedNumber[0];

    for (int checkNum = 0; checkNum < 20; checkNum += 1) {
        maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
        minNum = Math.min(minNum, inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
    }

    System.out.println("The maximum number: " + maxNum);
    System.out.println("The minimum number: " + minNum);
}
```

Comment: My Mistake. Thanks for pointing out, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you write it without using an array at all, you don't actually need to care whether it is 20, 50 or 1 million input numbers:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int maxNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int minNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, num);
  minNum = Math.min(minNum, num);
}

System.out.println("The maximum number: " + maxNum);
System.out.println("The minimum number: " + minNum);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add second parameter the methods `max(...)` and `min(...)` need tow `int` parameters:

```
  int maxNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int minNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 for( ....){
 maxNum = Math.max(maxNum ,inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
 minNum = Math.min(minNum ,inputtedNumber[checkNum]);
 }
```

Comment: This won't find the maximum and minimum number.